# Flutter List of button

Tags: list, flutter, button

I'm stuck with a really simple pb : i want to generate buttons without to define the list Index.

```
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    
      final mybuttons = ['button 1', 'button 2', 'button 3'];  // List defining the items
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.yellow[200], Colors.orange[300]])),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ButtonMenuList(mybuttons[0]),            //button 1
                        ButtonMenuList(mybuttons[1]),            //button 2
                        ButtonMenuList(mybuttons[2]),            //button 3
                      ]),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[Text(_usageRulesFr)],
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
      }

class ButtonMenuList extends StatelessWidget {
  final buttonmen;

  ButtonMenuList(this.buttonmen);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {//design button
    );
  }
}
```

This works but unstead repeating ButtonMenuList(), i'd like to automatically generate them depending on the List item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.yellow[200], Colors.orange[300]])),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      // Here
                      children: mybuttons.map((item) => ButtonMenuList(item)).toList());
                      // 
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[Text(_usageRulesFr)],
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
      }
```

Or, you can do:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
        for(var item in mybuttons) ButtonMenuList(item)
    ],
),
```

[Extra_refs](https://fireship.io/snippets/dart-how-to-get-the-index-on-array-loop-map/)